# asp.net using a different model in a partial view than in its parent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My `_Layout` page uses `@RenderSection` at a couple of points, for example to render the sidebars (if there are any). I have about 30 different views that use 10 different models where they get the content from. However there are only 4 different sidebars at the moment, so I out them into partial views that are called like this:

```
@section SBLeft {
    @Html.Partial("_SidebarTopics)
}
```

This works fine on my frontpage because the sidebar partial `_SidebarTopics` that is called from the `Frontpage\Index.cshtml` view uses the same model (`WebsiteStructureModel`) that is called at the start of the Index view:

```
@model Web.Areas.Public.Models.WebsiteStructureModel
```

Now I run into problems when I want to use a sidebar that uses Model A, if the "parent" view uses Model B. It results in an error like this:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Web.Areas.Public.Models.ProjectDetailsModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Web.Areas.Public.Models.WebsiteStructureModel'.
```

Using two `@model` statements at the beginning of the Index view does not work so I can't pass the second model explicitly to the sidebar as second parameter of the `@Html.Partial` command. And using a `@model` statement at the beginning of the partial view is ignored.

There must be some way to call a partial view and have that partial view use a specified model that may not neccessarily be the one used by the calling/parent view - Please help me understand how this can be done!

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways to do this.

### First way:

You could combine your 2 models into a view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public WebsiteStructureModel WebModel { get; set; }
    public ProjectDetailsModel ProjectModel { get; set; }
}
```

You'd obviously populate this in your `Action` and then pass that to the View

### Second way:

Rather than calling `@Html.Partial("_SidebarTopics")` you could create an `Action` in your controller which will `return PartialView("_SidebarTopics", model);` where `model` is the model passed into the partial view, for example:

```
@section SBLeft {
    @Html.Action("SidebarTopics", new { /* route params */ });
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SidebarTopics(/* route params */)
{
    var model = new ProjectDetailsModel();
    return PartialView("_SiderbarTopics", model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first solution seems easy enough, what are the downsides of that particular approach? The second solution seems to be more sophisticated and "compartmentalized". Could you please give a short "complete" code example of how I would "trigger" the action from the "main" view (using model A) to render the partial view (using model B)? I seem do miss something.

Comment: If you show some code on how you're currently populating your model, I will show you how to do it the first way.. I don't know how you're currently doing it..